# PHP - Convert Date to UTC Date

Tags: php, javascript, date, utc

I have a date pulled from my mysql database in the form YYYY-MM-DD.

Now I have some javascript that requires the dates like this:

```
data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9], 
            [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5], 
            [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
        ]
```

So I thought I could do the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
      $thedate = explode('-', $row['date']); //$row['date'] = YYYY-MM-DD      
      $str .= '[Date.UTC(' . $thedate[0].','.$thedate[1].','.$thedate[2].'), '.$row['answer'].'],';
      $i++;
    }
```

And then simply capture this in the browser side using an AJAX request in a variable `data`, giving:

```
data: [data]
```

When alerting the contents of data I notice I get something like the following for 22nd & 23rd August:

```
[Date.UTC(2011, 08, 22), 55], [Date.UTC(2011, 08, 23), 65]
```

When what I need is

```
[Date.UTC(2011, 7, 22), 55], [Date.UTC(2011, 7, 22), 65]
```

Can someone tell me how to convert convert the date pulled from the db relation into the correct format....

YYYY

Comment: are you asking how to substract 1 from $row[1]?

Answer (score 0):

Which format is that? Anyway, use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to parse the date, after that you can format it anyway you like.

Example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    $Date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $row['date'] ); 
    $str .= '[Date.UTC(' . $Date->format('Y') . ', ';
    $str .= $Date->format('n') - 1 . ', ';
    $str .= $Date->format('j') . '), ' . $row['answer'] . '],';
}
```

By the way, have a look at `json_encode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
  $timestamp = strtotime($row['date']); 
  $str .= '[Date.UTC(' . date('Y', $timestamp). ', ';
    $str .= date('n', $timestamp) - 1 . ', ';
    $str .= date('j', $timestamp) . '), ' . $row['answer'] . '],';
}
```

about DateTime - this is a great class but avaliable only for pphp >= 5.2